# Permutation and combinations,Dice problem,

Tags: combinatorics

What are the number of outcomes of 6 alike dice.
The answer is $\frac{11!}{5!6!}$

I need some help.Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that is the answer given ?

Comment: yea 11C5 is the answer given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the same logic as in your other question,

the answer is 6-combinations from 6 different numbers, that is alike to saying, choosing 6 numbers with repetitions from set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, (6 because there are 6 die)

so you can do directly as 6-combinations from 6 different objects are

$$\binom{6+6-1}{6} = \binom{11}{6} = \binom{11}{5}$$

or you can do that same thing arrange 5 bars (6 compartments) and 6 "*", total arrangements =

$$\frac{11!}{5!6!}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  You have $6$ numbers and you have to make $6$ choices from them.  You should start by answering two questions.

(1) Can the same number be chosen more than once?  For example, is $1,1,1,2,3,3$ possible?

(2) Is the order important?  For example, is $1,1,1,2,3,3$ the same outcome as $1,2,3,1,3,1$?

If you can answer these you should be able to identify this question as a standard problem which I expect you have studied in classes/lectures or your textbook.

Comment: Is the answer mentioned in question correct ?

Comment: @lsp Yes, it is. Think multisets (or "combinations with repetition")

Comment: Thanks. Will refer multisets for further information